# How to Preload Reactjs microfrontend once an HTML site is loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, micro-frontend

We provide easy payment UI for shopify stores, so when customer clicks on buy now button we open a modal with renders reactjs application. now can we prefetch these reactjs files once the customer opens the shopify store and even before clicking the buynow button??

Let me know if its possible or not

Comment: ummm, how can you preload when the site is loaded?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of the link tag with the rel attribute set to "prefetch" in the HTML code of your Shopify store. By specifying the URLs of the ReactJS files in the href attribute of the link tag, the browser will fetch and cache these files in the background.

eg.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).